# xhr addEventListener not working in framework7

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I am trying to add a progressbar with percentage while uploading image in framework7 project. Inside ajax function I am unable to get inside the `xhr: function() {`. My code is below:

```
$$.ajax({
        url: apiurl,
        data: formData,
        type: "post",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        xhr: function() { // iam not getting here
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    console.log(percentComplete);
                    $('.newprogressbar span').html(Math.round(percentComplete * 100));
                }
            }, false);
            return xhr;
        },
        success: function(response){
            result = JSON.parse(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status){
            showweballmessages(lang.networkConnectError,1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: check it -> $$.ajax({ . You need just $.ajax({ .

Comment: Try setting your contentType to "application/json"

Comment: @SneakyMummin — The code implies they are posting a FormData object. That absolutely is not `application/json`.

Comment: i am using framrwork7 with cordova so $$ will not be the problem